# How to get current page number in vue-table-2 ? I'm using server-side table

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vue-tables-2

I'm using vue-tables-2 (server table) to display my table. I am using the built-in pagination of vue-tables-2.

When we refresh the table it will redirect us to the first page of table. I want to redirect the user to the page where it was before calling the refresh. So I want to know how to get the index of the current page so I can redirect the user to the specific page using set page.

```
v-server-table skin="table table-striped  text-left" name="Table" ref="Table" :url="route('materials.index', {id: $route.params.id}).toString()" :columns="columns" :options="options">
        </v-server-table>
<script>
   export default {
            props :['id'],
            data(){
                return {
                       }
                  }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the the [events page of the documentation](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/events). You can use the `vue-tables.pagination` event to save the last page the used has accessed.